# CL error C1189 with vadefs.h in compilation

Tags: c, windows, compilation, cl

first of all I want to reduce the size of my executable,
I was using the gcc compiler.
I'm looking to compile with the cl.exe in windows compiler, it has properties that are more interesting

Without using the flags I would like to use this command

```
cl /I "C:\Users\Prince 2 lu\Desktop\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include" main.c
```

in a very tiny test code

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("hello world");
    return 1;
}
```

who just include the default library and print.
The result:

```
Optimization compiler Microsoft (R) C/C++ version 19.29.30140 for ARM64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. all rights reserved.

main.c
C:\Users\Prince 2 lu\Desktop\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\vadefs.h(92): fatal error C1189: #error:  VARARGS not implemented for this TARGET
```

content of the vadefs.h file:

```c
#if defined (__GNUC__)
/* Use GCC builtins */

(...)
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
/* MSVC specific */

#if defined(_M_IA64)
(...)
#endif

#if defined(_M_IX86)

(...)
#elif defined(_M_AMD64)

(...)
#elif defined(_M_IA64)

#error VARARGS not implemented for IA64

#else

#error VARARGS not implemented for this TARGET
```

i also tried to define each constants
_M_AMD64 and _M_IX86 defined the compiler print lot of errors

```
C:\Users\Prince 2 lu\Desktop\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\stdio.h(599): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
(...)
C:\Users\Prince 2 lu\Desktop\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\swprintf.inl(34): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
```

how can i compile this simple code main.c without theres errors ?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you adding a mingw-w64 header path when compiling with Microsoft's C compiler?

Comment: Also you appear to be using an ARM64 target and all of those tests are for other architectures. (And makes using that x86_64 include directory even more off)

Comment: I'm also looking to include the include-path, without it cl doesn't recognize <stdio.h>, because the path isn't specified @Shawn

Comment: The MS compiler has its own standard headers etc. that it uses. If it's not seeing them, something is messed up with its installation or your environment.

Comment: You can't use the standard headers from a different compiler, they are specific for their relative compiler. Moreover MS C compiler is the less compliant C compiler...

Comment: I think my problem with libraries comes from the fact that I was executing my commands from visual studio code and not visual studio (in my case 2019), from the terminal I have more conclusive results